# A certain converse of Hölder's inequality for $L^\infty$ space.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

So this question is Chapter 8, Q2, from the book by Wheeden and Zygmund which is related to Hölder's inequality. Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$. A function $f$ is said to be in $L^p(E)$ if $f$ is measurable, and if $\int_E |f|^p$ is finite for $p<\infty$, or if $f$ is essentially bounded for $p=\infty$.

I need to show that given a Lebesgue measurable function $f$ on $E\subset\mathbb R^n$, if $fg\in L^1(E)$ for every Lebesgue measurable $g$ satisfying $g\in L^1(E)$, then $f\in L^\infty(E)$. I notice this question is similar to [This question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37832/on-the-h%C3%B6lder-inequality), but my assumption is a bit weaker.

My attempt is to prove the contrapositive: Assume $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$, then construct a $g\in L^1(E)$ such that $\int_E fg=+\infty$. By using the converse of Hölder's inequality we know that the assumption leads to
$$\sup_{\|g\|_1\leq 1}\int_E fg=\infty$$
which means there is a sequence $\{g_n\}\in L^1(E)$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_E fg_n=\infty.$$

This seems to very closed to the result I wanted, but I was hoping a single function $g\in L^1(E)$ can be constructed such that $\int_E fg=+\infty$. I know the unit ball in the Banach space $L^1(E)$ is not compact, generally. Thus it is no guarantee that $\{g_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence, e.t.c. The other attempt was to use Fatou's lemma on the sequence $\{g_n\}$, maybe define $g(x)=\liminf_n g_n(x)$? But I'm not so familiar with the Fatou's lemma, and have no idea is it true that $g\in L^1(E)$ and $\int_E fg$ will be infinite.

How could one construct a $g$ such that $\int_E fg=\infty$? A direct proof is also appreciated.

Comment: There exists a function of the type $\sum a_n\mu\{x: k_n \leq |f| <k_n\}$ satsfying your requirements. I am not posting an answer because it has been answered many times on MSE.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you, I notice this hint from the book too. Can you post a link here? I couldn't find this question on MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k:=\{x\in\mathbb R^n, \lvert f(x)\rvert\geqslant k\}$. If we assume that $\lVert f\rVert_\infty=\infty$, then $\lambda(A_k)$ is positive for each $k$. But it is possible that  $\lambda(A_k)$ is infinite. However, consider $B_k:= A_k\cap B(0, N)$ for $N$ large enough (with $B(0,N)=\{x\in\mathbb R^n,\lvert x\rvert <N\}$) so that $\lambda(B_k)>0$.

Let $(c_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_k c_k$ is finite but $\sum_k kc_k$ is infinite and let
$$
g=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}a_k\operatorname{sgn}(f)\frac{\mathbf{1}(B_k)}{\lambda(B_k)},
$$
where $\operatorname{sgn}(f)(x)=1$ if $f(x)>0$, $-1$ if $f(x)<0$ and $0$ if $f(x)=0$.

Then $g\in L^1$ but $$fg\geqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 1}a_k k\frac{\mathbf{1}(B_k)}{\lambda(B_k)},$$
which is not integrable.

Comment: This idea is fantastic! However, what if the measure of $A_k$s are not finite? In the case $f(x)=x$ defined on $(0,\infty)$, then each $A_k$ would be of infinite measure.

Comment: @kelvinhong方 That's the problem when one is too used with probability theory :). I have edited.

Comment: Is it possible to go with $B_k:= A_k\cap B(0,r_k)$ where $r_k$ is large enough so that $B_k$ is of positive measure? Because from my example $f(x)=x$ it seems if $N$ is fixed, then $B_k$ will be eventually empty.

Comment: Actually $k$ is fixed and you let $N$ going to infinity,